# how can i update a field in firestore database with google cloud function when another field changes?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to write a simple google cloud function for firestore database which updates a field in a document when another field changes at the same document. The triggered field is named "copper" and the updates will be done to the field "coppervalue". I wrote a simple function for this, it doesnt give any error but it doesnt update the field "coppervalue" either, so i would like to learn where i am doing wrong.

Here is my cloud function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.copperupdate = functions.firestore
        .document("/kullanici/{uid}")
        .onUpdate((change,context) => {
            const newfieldvalue = change.after.data();
            const fieldname = newfieldvalue.name;
            if(fieldname==="copper"){
                const d = new Date();
                const currenttime = d.getTime();
                const coppervalue = snap.data()['coppervalue'];
                const copperdate = snap.data()['copperdate'];
                const copperdec = (currenttime-copperdate)/1000
                const copper_real= (copperdec*copper/60)+coppervalue;
                const sonuccopper = Math.trunc(copper_real)
                return change.after.ref.set({
                    coppervalue: sonuccopper
                }, {merge: true});
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out;

My mistake was i thought newfieldvalue.name was accessing the name of the field instead it was accessing "name" field so i made a few changes, here is the code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.copperupdate = functions.firestore
        .document("/kullanici/{uid}")
        .onUpdate((change,context) => {
            const newfieldvalue = change.after.data();
            const previousfieldvalue = change.before.data();
            if (newfieldvalue.copper === previousfieldvalue.copper){
                return false;
            }else{
                const d = new Date();
                const currenttime = d.getTime();
                const copper = newfieldvalue.copper;
                const coppervalue = newfieldvalue.coppervalue;
                const copperdate = newfieldvalue.copperdate;
                const copperdec = (currenttime-copperdate)/1000
                const copper_real= (copperdec*copper/60)+coppervalue;
                const sonuccopper = Math.trunc(copper_real)
                return change.after.ref.set({
                    coppervalue: sonuccopper
                }, {merge: true});
            }
        });
```